# Gstreamer audio input to mp3

Tags: c, audio, mp3, gstreamer, microphone

I am trying to create a simple program using `Gstreamer` to take the input from a microphone and save it to a mp3 file. I keep getting

> Internal data flow error

and can´t seem to find the problem(I am new to `Gstreamer`). 
Here is a link to my code:

http://pastebin.com/QDexe8Fz

Comment: It's best to paste the code into your question. I won't even look at it where it is being hosted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not handling return codes from the functions. As a result your in the dark when it fails. Anyway in your code you forgot to link the elements. Right after line 70, also do gst_element_link_many(....);

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the **GStreamer package doesn't include support for MP3**. However, you can go after codecs and plugins to make it support.